# Can i = v.end() be optimized out of a for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

I saw something like this just now:

```
vector<int> x { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (auto i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

is it better to do this:

```
vector<int> x { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (auto i = x.begin(), end = x.end(); i != end; ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

I guess I figured that the optimizer would take care of this.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes the expression does get evaluated every time but the compiler usually optimizes it. If you turn off compiler optimization, it is better to use the latter one

Comment: Compare assembly and see.

Comment: (Also, the second version is wrong if the loop body might `erase` from `x`.)

Comment: Because it's late and I'm not thinking clearly. :p

Comment: @texasbruce *"If you turn off compiler optimization, it is better to use the latter one"* - If you turn off optimization, you obviously don't care about performance, anyway.

Comment: Meh, if the compiler doesn't restructure it the way you did, then he at least will inline that puny `end()` call anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the second version can be more optimal, so long as your container is never modified *but* the compiler cannot tell the container is never modified.

The "most optimal" looping structure can be found by examining the C++11 ranged-based `for` loop.

The code:

```
for( auto x : vec_expression ) {
  // body
}
```

is translated roughly into:

```
{
  auto&& __container = vec_expression;
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto&& __end = end(container)
  for( auto __it = begin(container); __it != __end; ++__it ) {
    auto x = *__it;
    {
      // body
    }
  }
}
```

where any variable starting with `__` exists for exposition purposes only, and the `using std::begin; using std::end;` is magically removed from consideration within `// body`.  (Remember, any variable containing `__` is reserved for the compiler implementation).

If you have lambda support in your compiler, you can write your own version:

```
template<typename Container, typename Lambda>
void foreach( Container&& c, Lambda&& f ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto&& e = end(c);
  for( auto it = begin(c); it != e; ++it ) {
    f(*it);
  }
}
```

which is used like this:

```
foreach( vec_expression, [&]( int x ) {
} );
```

it does not let you break, or return into the outer scope, but it is pretty close to C++11 ranged-based for.

If you lack both ranged-based for and lambdas, you could be a completely insane person and implement much of the above as a macro...   Do the `std::begin` work using a helper function with perfect fowarding to avoid polluting the body of the function, mayhap.

Answer (score 5):

Most probably the optimizer will do the job for you.

By the way, why `decltype(x.begin())` when there's `auto` for you?

```
for (auto i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); ++i)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

or even:

```
for (auto i : x)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

The latter is the `range for`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for.

Comment: Because it's late and I'm not thinking clearly. :P :D  As for the 2nd, MSVS 2010 doesn't support that syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. Because some operations like `erase` may invalidate the iterator.

If you are sure there's no such operations inside the `for` loop, feel free to do so. But usually the compiler will do the optimization for you. (if you turn optimization flag on)

Comment: Hmmmm, I usually go backwards when I use `erase` to stop that from happening anyway.